# Difference between 'sentimental' and 'emotional'?

Tags: differences, synonyms

What is the difference between the terms 'sentimental' and 'emotional'?

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sentimental http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/emotional

Comment: As asked, you are best served by just looking them up in a dictionary. If you are more specific, you will get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sentimental to indicate mood, as in someone who reflects on his/her feelings.

Use emotional to indicate someone who reacts to events by expressing what he/she feels.

Sentimental connotes an internalized feeling, emotional an expressive one.